# Cannot resolve symbol 'activity_main' in android studio

Tags: android

I'm facing a problem. I am getting the error "Cannot resolve symbol 'activity_main'. I read the other posts about it, and could not figure out how to fix it. Here is my code :

```
package com.grasland.musicplayer.Activities;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.grasland.musicplayer.R;



public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Get the ViewPager and set it's PagerAdapter so that it can display items
        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(new SampleFragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),
                MainActivity.this));

        // Give the TabLayout the ViewPager
        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    }
}
```

There is a screen of my project's tree :

[Tree project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rEIVp.png)

Thanks !

Comment: can you post a screen of your project structure expanding the activity path? It is possible that your activity class is in a different folder, so the resource is not correctly located

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the name of the main activity's layout file is "activity_main". If its not, rename it to "activity_main". If the name is already correct, try Build → Clean Project.

Comment: I think that was the problem ! Thank you ! (I am a newbie in Android developpement).

Comment: Now that I saw the project tree I see that the problem is the name. But normally that is automatically handled by Android Studio. How did you create your activities?

Comment: I recommend renaming the layout file rather than the Java Class file.